# single or plural with "mixture of "

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I wonder what is the correct verb with my following sentence:

> Mixture of Gaussians show a good model fit.

or

> mixture of Gaussian shows a good model fit.

I think the second one is correct, but someone told me that I should choose the first one.

Comment: I would write "A mixture of Gaussians shows a good model fit" but I don't understand the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: What is a mixture of Gaussians??  Gaussian is an adjective, not a noun. A Gaussian function or Gaussian distribution. There is no mixture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject in your sentence (in both of them actually) is *mixture*. *Mixture* is singular, so the verb should be singular.

In essence:

> the mixture shows [singular subject]

*or*

> the mixtures show [plural subject]

---

The use of *Gaussians* versus *Gaussian* is a red herring in terms of the verb—although is still important in terms of the subject phrase.

Normally a mixture is a mixture of multiple things.

Also, the word [*Gaussian*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Gaussian) is an adjective, not a noun, and it is normally applied to *curve* or *distribution*.

All in all, the most likely correct sentence is the following (with the addition of an article or demonstrative pronoun at the start):

> (A / The / This) **mixture** of *Gaussian (curves / distributions)* **shows** a good model fit.